# How to change the line break direction to keep the old line on top and new line to break downwards if I write from left to rigth?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I made a mini application using vue, which is translating a text into hungarian rovas script. Each hungarian letter is associated with 1 symbol.
But the translated script must be written from rigth to left. Each letter is drawn 1 by 1 and saved as a png image. The application checks the input text letter by letter and renders the corresponding image from rigth to left.
My problem is that the line breaks upwards. So the oldest line gets to the bottom. I want to keep the first line at the top. How can I reverse the line break so its not pushing the old line(line of images)downwards but upwards? 
here is the app:
https://murmuring-badlands-73974.herokuapp.com/

I have tried reversing the array and vice versa, trying other solution so i can start writing from left to rigth etc.
I am just curious if the line break could be manipulated the way i described.

```
<div class="inputtext">

 <label for="rovas">Fordítani kívánt szöveg:</label>
 <textarea class="rovas" id="rovasiras" cols="50" rows="5" v- 
   model="name"> 
 </textarea>              

<div class="translated">

   <template v-for="(betu, index) in betut().reverse()">

      <img v-bind:src="'./images/' + betu + '.png'"  height=" 25px"   
          style="margin: 5px" alt="-">              

   </template> 
</div>
</div>
```

The expected result should be a translated sentence or paragraph starting from right to left the first translated line always at the top..

Comment: Don’t reverse your input data, but simply have the images `float: right` …?

Comment: Maybe thats good too, but direction css property solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print in the normal way i,e left to right the insertion of any new line will come beneath the existing or old line ,Since you are using reverse function it all happens in the opposite way , it prints from right to left and insert the new line above the old line by pushing in down,

Answer:
   To overcome this we need to use dir="rtl" i,e you are indicating the direction as right to left. Find for reference Click [here](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir)

Comment: So If I understand it correctly. If I dont use reverse method on the array and instead I use rtl that solves the problem and it gives me the desired result?

Comment: Removing the reverse method from the arrray to print it from index 0 ltr and adding the css property of direction:"rtl" to the htm element solved the problem. Thanks